# Find locations using zip codes, cities or coordinates

Tags: geolocation, zipcode

I need to code a finder of cities in a radius of X km. of a given one using a ZIP code or a city. Something like this:

```
Enter ZIP code or city: [            ]
Choose Radius in Km.    (10) (20) (30)
-------------------------------------------
[ Submit ]
```

So I need a database relating zip codes, coordinates and city names. (not for USA, Germany)
Anyone know of any? Or a ready to use web service or whatever that allow me go to the beach earlier?

THX.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this:

http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodes?postalcode=8775&country=CH&radius=10&username=demo

http://www.geonames.org/export/client-libraries.html (several client libraries to request geonames service)

Exactly what I want for Christmas.
THX.-

Answer (score 0):

If you can get hold of the coordinates of each location (zipcode - longitude - latitude) you can calculate the distance

You could use http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/index.html to get the longitude and latitude for a place then use the calculation to create the distance.

[Calculating distance between zip codes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407989/calculating-distance-between-zip-codes-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I know what you say.
I asked for a database or web service to provide that data (zipcode - longitude - latitude).