# Given a zipcode, how to find out lat-long range that are within the area of that zipcode?

Tags: latitude-longitude, zipcode

so if I have the zipcode of say Manhattan, how do I find the lat-long range for that zipcode?  Is there a free database I can use?

Comment: check this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123338/find-locations-using-zip-codes-cities-or-coordinates][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123338/find-locations-using-zip-codes-cities-or-coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://www.boutell.com/zipcodes/.