# geo locations search with javascript

Tags: javascript, search, geolocation

Is there a way to create geo location search of closest points with javascript?
for example, we have a list of points with their coordinates. I need to find points ~ in 5km radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the harvesine-formula for Javascript and Google Maps.

Comment: You want to look for a space-filling-curve too. I've done an implementation in php ( hilbert-curve ). You can download it at phpclasses.org ( hilbert-curve ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [google geolocation API](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_geolocation.html)  or [Google map API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/)

Comment: sample? i don't need to show points on map
i'm trying to create some thing like find_closest([point1, point2 ...] ) // => [point1]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407989/calculating-distance-between-zip-codes-in-php , You can get find the closest places by giving a specific zip in google maps api.. Read the google api manual completely..