# Calculate distance between 2 post codes

Tags: php, mysql, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating distance between zip codes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407989/calculating-distance-between-zip-codes-in-php)

Let's say I have two different post codes with the same or different country. Is there any API to count the distance between those two? Thanks.

*Not necessary in PHP.*

Comment: I'm not familiar with any out-of-the-box PHP API that can do this.  I have a geo-location database for the USA that provides lat/long coordinates for each post code.  A MySQL query using trig (cosine and sine calculations I believe) can coordinate the distance between any two post codes.

Comment: Some postcodes (e.g. in the UK) sadly are copyrighted commercial property, and so you have to pay to get a copy of the postcode->coordinate database.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Google's geocoding service, which is now free of charge:

http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests

At least for germany, Google maps resolves

```
ZIP Code, Country
```

sequences like [on this page](http://maps.google.de/maps?q=24109,%20Deutschland&hl=de&sll=54.33934,10.145113&sspn=0.03958,0.108232&vpsrc=0&hnear=24109%20Kiel,%20Schleswig-Holstein&t=m&z=13).